# How is textarea's scrollHeight and clientHeight calculated?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When you run this snippet you will see the following (at least in Chrome 97.0.4692.71):

1. On page load, `clientHeight` and `scrollHeight` are more than is necessary for 1 line.
2. `line-height` is `undefined` unless explicitly set. Setting `line-height` affects the initial `clientHeight` and `scrollHeight` values.
3. Entering 1 line break doesn't change `clientHeight` or `scrollHeight`. They appear to initialize with enough room for 2 lines.
4. Entering 2 line breaks increases `scrollHeight`, as expected, but it doesn't equal `textHeight`.
5. Entering enough characters to wrap causes `scrollHeight` to increase but there are no line breaks added to the text (i.e. `textHeight` doesn't change).

What are the calculations used to arrive at the `clientHeight` and `scrollHeight` values observed?

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  resize(textarea);
});

textarea.addEventListener('input', (inputEvent) => {
  resize(inputEvent.target);
});

function resize(o) {
  const lines = getLines(o);
  const fontSize = getCSSIntegerValue(o, 'font-size');
  const padding = getCSSIntegerValue(o, 'padding');
  const borderWidth = getCSSIntegerValue(o, 'border-width');
  const textHeight = fontSize * lines;
  console.log('fontSize=%d, lines=%d, padding=%d, borderWidth=%d, textHeight=%d, clientHeight=%d, scrollHeight=%d', fontSize, lines, padding, borderWidth, textHeight, o.clientHeight, o.scrollHeight);
}

function getCSSIntegerValue(o, property) {
  const computedValues = window.getComputedStyle(o);
  const propertyValue = computedValues.getPropertyValue(property);
  return parseInt(propertyValue.replace(/\D/g, ''));
}

function getLines(o) {
  const lines = o.value.split(/\r|\r\n|\n/);
  return lines.length;
}
```

```css
textarea {
  all: unset;
  background-color: #ddd;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: medium;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: "They appear to initialize with enough room for 2 lines", the default [`rows`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#attr-textarea-rows) value is `2`, you can set it to something else if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

`line-height`, unless defined, is going to use the user agent stylesheet (typically **1.2** for desktop browsers, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#values).) With that information, the results should make more sense.

`clientHeight` is always `2 * line-height`.

`scrollHeight` is `line-height * lines`.

Comment: Thank you, that does answer a lot. Apparently the spec defines the default as `line-height: normal`, which means the user agent will define it (as you stated). Then my user agent defines it as `line-height: normal`. I'm curious if this circular reference is why `window.getComputedStyle(o).getPropertyValue('line-height')` doesn't return a value.

Comment: @Exide yeah, that's not what I would expect either. It should be returning `normal`, and the integer parsing should return `NaN`. I'm not able to replicate it returning `undefined`.

Comment: I should have said that `window.getComputedStyle(o).getPropertyValue('line-height')` doesn't return a computed value. It does indeed return `normal`. When I read this, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle, it makes me think `normal` would be resolved to a specific number.

Comment: @Exide if you're referring to the `line-height` example, it's being set to 2 with the this declaration: `font: 2rem/2 sans-serif;`. The `/2` is shorthand for setting the `line-height`.